# Problem collapsing levels of a factor in R

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a messy factor variable with more levels than it should have. The cases come from an open survey and many participants wrote with typos or just responded a similar answer in different ways.

This is a sample df that represent my problem:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=seq(1:10),
                 Nationality=c("espanol", "spaniol", "ESPANOL",
                               "spanish", "colombia", "Colombian",
                               "British", "brit", "ESPanol", "UK")
                               )
```

The output I would like is this:

```
> df
   ID Nationality
1   1     Spanish
2   2     Spanish
3   3     Spanish
4   4     Spanish
5   5   Colombian
6   6   Colombian
7   7     British
8   8     British
9   9     Spanish
10 10     British
```

This is what I have tried to do in order to reduce this 10 artificial levels of the factor to just 3 (Spanish, Colombian, British) as it should be:

```
library(forcats) 
                              
levels(df$Nationality) <- fct_collapse(df$Nationality, Spanish = c("espanol", "spaniol", "ESPANOL",
                                                                  "spanish", "ESPanol"),
                                                       Colombian = c("colombia", "Colombian"),
                                                       British = c("British", "brit", "UK")
                                        )
```

This effectively reduces my "nationality" factor to 3 levels, but the output is looks like this and does not correspond to anything similar to the first one:

```
> df
   ID Nationality
1   1   Colombian
2   2     British
3   3     British
4   4     Spanish
5   5     Spanish
6   6     Spanish
7   7     Spanish
8   8     Spanish
9   9   Colombian
10 10     British
```

In the bigger dataset I am working with, it does not work either, but the output is worse in the sense that all cases become "Spanish" and I have no single cue about why this could be happening.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Best,
Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making Nationality a factor first?

```
df <- data.frame(ID=seq(1:10),
                 Nationality=c("espanol", "spaniol", "ESPANOL",
                               "spanish", "colombia", "Colombian",
                               "British", "brit", "ESPanol", "UK")
)
library(forcats) 


df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Nationality = factor(Nationality)) %>% 
 mutate(Nationality = fct_collapse(Nationality, Spanish = c("espanol", "spaniol", "ESPANOL", "spanish", "ESPanol"),
                                       Colombian = c("colombia", "Colombian"),
                                       British = c("British", "brit", "UK")))



#more concise

mutate(across(Nationality, ~ fct_collapse(factor(.), 
Spanish = c("espanol", "spaniol", "ESPANOL", "spanish", "ESPanol"), 
Colombian = c("colombia", "Colombian"), 
British = c("British", "brit", "UK")
)))
```

Comment: or `mutate_across(Nationality, ~ fct_collapse(factor(.), Spanish=...))`

Comment: mutate_* is now deprecated. mutate(across(Nationality, ~ fct_collapse(factor(.), Spanish = c("espanol", "spaniol", "ESPANOL", "spanish", "ESPanol"),
                                          Colombian = c("colombia", "Colombian"),
                                          British = c("British", "brit", "UK"))))

Comment: sorry, that underscore was a typo. (I do know that `mutate_*` is deprecated: did `mutate_across()` ever even exist?)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. However, i am confused... I never explicitly declared my variable as a factor, but the only reason for this is because when using ```str(df$Nationality)``` the output was telling me that this was already a factor. How is that possible?

Comment: As I mentioned in other answer, your code solved the issue. However, the issue never was that it was not a factor before, older version of R treated it as a factor before and using the same code changing it to factor before does not give the expected output. I am curious about the reason why my code is not working properly so I learn from my mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions using built-in functions:

#### Solution 1

This solution assumes that column `Nationality` is a character variable

```
cases <- c(espanol = "Spanish", spaniol = "Spanish", ESPANOL = "Spanish", spanish = "Spanish", 
           British = "British", brit = "British", ESPanol = "Spanish", UK = "British",
           colombia = "Colombian", Colombian = "Colombian")

df$Nationality <- factor(cases[df$Nationality])
```

#### solution 2

```
df$Nationality <- as.factor(df$Nationality)

levels(df$Nationality) <- list(Spanish = c("espanol", "spaniol", "ESPANOL", "spanish", "ESPanol"),
                               Colombian = c("colombia", "Colombian"),
                               British = c("British", "brit", "UK"))
```

output data

```
#    ID Nationality
# 1   1     Spanish
# 2   2     Spanish
# 3   3     Spanish
# 4   4     Spanish
# 5   5   Colombian
# 6   6   Colombian
# 7   7     British
# 8   8     British
# 9   9     Spanish
# 10 10     British
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. However, the problem seemed to be the same as I did not transform ```df$Nationality```to factor. I don't get it, because it was supposed to be a factor already as the ```str(df$Nationality)```function showed.

Comment: Note that there was an ambiguity in your question. When describing it, you talked about factor variable but in the reproducible example, you provided the variable `Nationality` as a character. It was better to provide it as a factor. If your variable was already a factor, then you just need the second part of solution 2.

Comment: This is because I am not very proficient in R as I haven't started long ago. I understand that unless specified, strings are treated as characters in R, but what I don't understand then is why this happens:


`str(df$Nationality)`
 
`Factor w/ 10 levels "brit","British",..: 5 8 7 9 3 4 2 1 6 10 `

Comment: This is very likely because you are using an R version older than 4.0.0.. From R 4.0.0, the default value of the `data.frame` argument `stringsAsFactors ` was changed from `TRUE` to `FALSE`. Run `R.version.string` to check the version you are using. If it is older than 4.0.0 (that is, it starts with a number lower than 4), then you need to add an additional argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to `data.frame` function when creating your data.set to read characters variables as such.. Something like `df <- data.frame(ID=..., Nationality=..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE). Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: continue: Something like `df <- data.frame(ID=..., Nationality=..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: I uploaded the version of R I was using and you are right, now strings are not factors. The code you and the other answer provided solved the issue, however it was not related with `df$Nationality` not being a factor... The problem has to be related with a mistake I might had with my code. Anyway, your solution helped! Thanks.